# Upload photo via graph API - multipart/form-data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

I am trying to create page post links in my page using Graph API. I was able to create the post, but I am having some problems sending the picture to use on it.

I was trying to use pictures that are in my computer, but i found out (here in stackoverflow) that I need to use URLs that are already in the internet or upload the photos from my computes to Facebook first, so I can use then later.

I checked to see how can I upload the photos from my computer via Graph API, and then use this URL for the picture in my post, but i saw that I need to do it using multipart/form-data.

But I didn't understand how to do it (upload photos and get their URL) using  multipart/form-data. Does anyone have an ideia how to do it?

Here's is the PHP code that I am using now:

```
<?php


session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookClientException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );



use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app','password');

$session = new FacebookSession('token');


$message = 'Test';
$link = "http://www.example.com.br";
$description = 'Description';
$name = 'Name';
$caption = 'Caption';
// $picture = 'file:///C:/Users/VIrgilio/Desktop/Petlove/Facebook%20Ads/Campanhas/Assento/Link/Assento-Novo.png'; //this is where the picture is in my PC

    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      '/page_id/feed',
      array (
        'message' => $message,
        'link' => $link,
        'description' => $description,
        'published' => 'false',
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
//      'picture' => $picture,  //    the URL from my PC gives me an error, here is where I need to put the URL from the uploaded photo
        )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you try 'picture' => '@' . $picture, but remove the file:///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use url from your computer. Here in this example, you have to use publicly available image. I mean to say image should be on internet.

For e.g. image hosted on domain example.com have real path like this

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/stack/stack-theme/images/stack-logo.png
```

and you have to provide path in this way.

If you want to upload image from your computer and post it on Facebook then use `multipart/form-data`.

Read this documentation for clarity: [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/photos#publish).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookFile/

`$fb->fileToUpload($image_path),`

Full example:

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// create instance of Facebook\Facebook class
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
    'app_id'  => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    'default_access_token' => $token,
));
$fb = &$facebook;

// Setup facebook post info
$data = array(
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($image_path),
    'caption' => $message,
);

// Send the request to Graph
try {
       $response = $fb->post("/$page_id/photos", $data);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
}

var_export($response);
```